# How to use an intermediate certificates with mojolicious

Tags: perl, ssl-certificate, mojolicious

Mojolicious lets me specify an ssl certificate and key when starting the app:

```
> ./myapp.pl prefork --listen 'https://*:8485&cert=my.crt&key=my.key'
```

I am trying todo this with a rapidssl certificate. 
Connecting to this service results in wget being rather unhappy:

```
$ wget https://example.com:8485/
--2016-06-22 09:50:49--  https://example.com:8485/
Resolving example.com (example.com)... 1.3.2.4
Connecting to example.com (example.com)|1.3.2.4|:8485... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify example.com's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to example.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

No big surprise, since when using rapidssl certs in other applications I have
to specify an intermediate certificate as well. So I tried to add this here too by concatenating the intermediate cert to the site certificate, but this has no influence on the outcome.

I also tried to put the intermediate certificate along with the root cert into a separate file and start with:

```
> ./myapp.pl prefork --listen 'https://*:8485&cert=my.crt&key=my.key&ca=myca.crt'
```

but the result was equally uninspiring:

```
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

please advise.

Comment: According to https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Server::Daemon#listen your second attempt should work.

Comment: I did read the docs :) or so I think ...

Comment: You don't need to specify CA param, because CA param is CLIENT CA, not server CA (used to verify client certificate, but you have only server).

Comment: Try to run this command: `openssl s_server -cert cert=my.crt -key my.key -accept 8485` and client in another console `openssl s_client -connect example.com:8485`. And looking on output (valid certificate or not). Mojolicious works only with valid certificate. If your certificate not have intermediate certificate, you need to concatenate both certificate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the server to send not only the leaf (servers) certificate but also any other (intermediate) certificates to the client then you simply add these to the cert file in the correct order. This means your my.crt should look like this

```
----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MII... the leaf certificate
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MII... the first intermediate certificate, i.e. the one which signed the leaf cert
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
...
```